# Max() + group by not working as expected in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `order_order_status` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `order_order_status_order_status_id_index` (`order_status_id`),
  KEY `order_order_status_order_id_index` (`order_id`),
  KEY `order_order_status_created_at_index` (`created_at`),
  KEY `order_order_status_updated_at_index` (`updated_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `order_order_status`
--

INSERT INTO `order_order_status` (`id`, `order_status_id`, `order_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1, 2, 1, '2016-10-01 01:57:37', '2016-10-01 01:57:37'),
(2, 2, 2, '2016-10-01 01:57:54', '2016-10-01 01:57:54'),
(3, 2, 3, '2016-10-02 02:12:49', '2016-10-02 02:12:49'),
(4, 6, 3, '2016-10-02 02:14:19', '2016-10-02 02:14:19');
```

What i want to select is:

```
1, 2, 1, '2016-10-01 01:57:37', '2016-10-01 01:57:37'
2, 2, 2, '2016-10-01 01:57:54', '2016-10-01 01:57:54'
4, 6, 3, '2016-10-02 02:14:19', '2016-10-02 02:14:19'
```

that is the newest entry of order_order_status grouped by order_id

now the problem:

running

```
select *, max(created_at) from `order_order_status` group by `order_order_status`.`order_id`
```

returns me:

[image]

or in prosa

it returns me NOT the newest entry, instead it returns the older one for order_id 3

Comment: MySQL doesn't guarantee which row will be returned in this case.  It just picks one "randomly". In that sense, it's working as expected. ["the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

Answer (score 2):

MySQL is working *exactly* as expected.  The problem is your expectations.

`select *` with a `group by` doesn't make sense.  You want to get the maximum, do something like this:

```
select oos.*
from order_order_status
where oos.created_at = (select max(oos2.created_at)
                        from order_order_status oos2
                        where oos2.order_id = oos.order_id
                       );
```

Aggregation (`group by`) produces one row per group.  An aggregation function such as `max()` gets the maximum value of a column -- nothing more.  It just operates on a column.

When you use `select *`, you have a bunch of columns that are not in the `group by` and not the arguments to aggregation columns.  MySQL allows this syntax (unfortunately -- few other databases do).  The values for the unaggregated columns are arbitrary values from indeterminate rows in the group.

Comment: ` from group by` ? oos and oos2 arent defined

Comment: why not just use something simpler like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18221999/group-by-having-max-date/35985225#35985225

Comment: @Toskan . . . There was a typo in my query.  And, this is going to work best with an index on `order_order_status(order_id, created_at)`.  Without that index, putting the subquery in the `where` clause would probably have better performance.

Answer (score 0):

using order by order_id desc may solve your problem

```
select *, max(created_at) from `order_order_status` group by `order_order_status`.`order_id` order by `order_order_status`.`order_id` desc
```