# MySQL inner join to get max(date) too inefficient on large table

Tags: mysql, database

**Property (houses) table: 22 million rows** - **EPC table: 14 million rows**

Both tables have duplicate houses with different INSPECTION_DATE's.

The following statement works fine but results include duplicate houses. I only want to return the latest house (max(INSPECTION_DATE)).

```
SELECT 
    property.paon,
    property.saon,
    property.street,
    property.postcode,
    property.lastSalePrice,
    DATE(property.lastTransferDate),
    epc.ADDRESS1,
    epc.POSTCODE,
    epc.TOTAL_FLOOR_AREA,
    epc.INSPECTION_DATE,
    GLENGTH(LINESTRINGFROMWKB(LINESTRING(GEOMFROMTEXT(ASTEXT(POINTFROMWKB(POINT(longitude, latitude)))),
                            GEOMFROMTEXT(ASTEXT(POINTFROMWKB(POINT(-2.13609, 53.61405))))))) * 100 AS distance
FROM
    property property
        INNER JOIN
    epc ON property.postcode = epc.POSTCODE
        AND CONCAT(property.paon, ', ', property.street) = epc.ADDRESS1 
WHERE
    property.lastTransferDate >= CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 5 YEAR

HAVING distance < 1.2
ORDER BY property.lastTransferDate DESC
LIMIT 10
```

I have tried the following statement with the help of a similar question ([SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)) but I'm not entirely sure I've implemented it correctly.

Would appreciate someone to help me with my statement so I could identify and better understand for my use-case

```
    SELECT 
    property.paon,
    property.saon,
    property.street,
    property.postcode,
    property.lastSalePrice,
    DATE(property.lastTransferDate),
    epc.ADDRESS1,
    epc.POSTCODE,
    epc.TOTAL_FLOOR_AREA,
    GLENGTH(LINESTRINGFROMWKB(LINESTRING(GEOMFROMTEXT(ASTEXT(POINTFROMWKB(POINT(longitude, latitude)))),
                            GEOMFROMTEXT(ASTEXT(POINTFROMWKB(POINT(-2.13609, 53.61405))))))) * 100 AS distance
FROM
    property property
        INNER JOIN 
    epc ON property.postcode = epc.POSTCODE
        AND (select max(epc.INSPECTION_DATE) from epc WHERE CONCAT(property.paon, ', ', property.street) = epc.ADDRESS1)
WHERE
    property.lastTransferDate >= CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 5 YEAR 

HAVING distance < 1.2
ORDER BY property.lastTransferDate DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Example result illustrating issue:
[Statement Result Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKgL7.png)

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Maybe this post would help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18221999/group-by-having-max-date

Comment: whiout a proper data sample is not possible procede valid code  ..

Comment: You can put a "First-cut bounding box" around your circle. that reduce the rows to filter and the query can use a index on long, lat and date . see:  https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-db.html

Comment: @scaisEdge I've added "Example result illustrating issue" at the bottom of my post. Thanks

Comment: @scaisEdge fyi... the query worked (with distance < 50000)... but it took 284 seconds to execute. Do you know any way to improve efficiency?

Comment: 50000 ?? what are meters ?  have you tried  with 10000 .. or  less ?

Comment: but which index you have on the property and epc tables ??

Comment: Yes I tried with < 1.2 at first (miles) but to try speed up query I put 50000 just to see if it worked. Now I know it works, it just needs more efficiency